# Binding one class to two layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

In my app, I have a `Product` class which is shown in two different ways: A normal card with all the information and a small card which only shows some of the its data.

So, I have two layouts: `product_card.xml` and `product_card_small.xml`.

Now, **can I bind these two layouts to the same `Product` class?**

Both layouts have this:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.MyTest.android.Models.Product"/>
    <variable name="product" type="Product"/>
</data>
```

And I have one `productsAdapter` which selects one of the layouts. But, when I want to use both `ProductCardBinding` and `ProductCardSmallBinding` in its viewHolder, only one of them (`ProductCardBinding`) is recognized. The other can't get resolved.

I want to know is it possible and if so, why does it only resolve one of them?

Comment: not sure if this helps, have you checked the includes section in the documentation? http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#includes

Comment: @Yazan, I don't have any problem with data binding and binding only one layout. The problem is with two layouts binding to one class...

Comment: ok, so they are not displayed at the same time, sorry i misunderstood ur question

Comment: Please add code of Adapter. It possible. Looks like you doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue. As one XML can bind to only one `ViewDataBinding`, you basically cannot do this. My current solution is use a proxy class. In your case, if `ProductCardBinding` and `ProductCardSmallBinding` both have one `TextView` and `ImageView`, then `ProductCardBindingProxy` looks like this:

```
class ProductCardBindingProxy {
    val someText: TextView
    val someImage: ImageView
    val viewDataBinding: ViewDataBinding

    constructor(productCardBinding: ProductCardBinding) {
        viewDataBinding = productCardBinding
        someImage = productCardBinding.image
        someText = productCardBinding.text
    }

    constructor(productCardSmallBinding: ProductCardSmallBinding) {
        viewDataBinding = productCardSmallBinding
        someImage = productCardSmallBinding.image
        someText = productCardSmallBinding.text
    }
}
```

then you can use this in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
val proxy = ProductCardBindingProxy(viewBinder)
ProductCardViewHolder(proxy)
```

I don't think this is a good solution, but this can solve it at least. :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do like this.I never use it.

```
<data class=".Item1">
    <import type="com.MyTest.android.Models.Product"/>
    <variable name="product" type="Product"/>
</data>
<data class=".Item2">
    <import type="com.MyTest.android.Models.Product"/>
    <variable name="product" type="Product"/>
</data>
```